# Why does the 2nd line of a Python script affect how pip installs it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip

**The problem**: `pip3 install` and `setuptools` munges the shebang line of shell scripts in an unexpected way.  I am trying to understand how it works and how to control it.

**What happens**: On macOS 10.13, I'm using Python 3.5 installed by [macports](https://www.macports.org).  I've developed Python 3 packages that currently can be installed by the following simple procedure:

```
git clone https://github.com/project/mypackage.git
cd mypackage
sudo pip3 install .
```

The `setup.py` for the packages contains the following:

```
scripts = ['bin/somescript'],
```

Each such script has the following first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Today, I discovered that `pip3` munges the shebang line during installation in a way that *depends on the second line of the script*.  In particular, if the start of my script looks like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
# some comments here
```

then `pip3 install` replaces the first line with `#!/usr/bin/X11/python3`, which happens to be completely wrong on my system. However, if the start of my script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# some comments here
```

`pip3 install` replaces the shebang line with a *different* (this time correct) path, `#!/opt/local/bin/python3`.

**My questions**: Basically, **why is this happening**?

1. Why does the second line of the script change the behavior?
2. How does `pip3 install` choose which interpreter it uses?
3. Why does it attempt to use `/usr/bin/X11/python3` (which doesn't exist on my system)?
4. How can I change the behavior or stop the munging altogether?

Comment: Can you create and post a simplified, minimal example project that reproduces this error, so we don't have to speculate about the other contents of your project?

Comment: @user2357112 yeah, a reasonable idea, but it'll take some time... Will try to do it soon.